# automatic volume management extension/tool

Tags: windows, volume-control

I study in noisy places sometimes. And when I am reading I like to use White Noise to drown everything out. But when I am watching a lecture and pause midway to think. I am again at the mercy of the outside world. So what I need is a way to make it so that when nothing else is playing, noise starts to play automatically. It could keep playing at a lower volume while I am watching a lecture. But as soon as I pause the lecture it should bump up the volume of noise. It could be a browser extension, as I use [a soft murmur](https://asoftmurmur.com) for White Noise, I also play online music in the background sometimes, so it should work on that.

I don't have enough money for noise cancelling headphones. Please tell me if such a solution exists regardless of price but preferably free. I'm using Windows-10.